# Which is the better way to use CASE in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, case

I'm curious which is better in these queries (performance or anything).

```
    SELECT some_column,
    CASE case_column
         WHEN 1 THEN 'a'
         WHEN 2 THEN 'a'
         WHEN 3 THEN 'a'
         WHEN 5 THEN 'b'
         WHEN 6 THEN 'b'
         ...
    END AS case_column_str
    FROM some_table ORDER BY case_column_str
```

or

```
    SELECT some_column,
    CASE 
         WHEN case_column=1 OR case_column=2 OR case_column=3 THEN 'a'
         WHEN case_column=5 OR case_column=6 THEN 'b'
         ...
    END AS case_column_str
    FROM some_table ORDER BY case_column_str
```

Does either of these queries have advantages over the other? Are there any significant differences between the two except for the second being able to use other field for more filtering? What if I'm just going to filter a single column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any decent optimizer will treat the two as essentially identical; it is very unlikely you'll be able to measure the difference in performance.  Oracle has a decent enough optimizer that you'll be hard-pressed to measure the difference at all.  You could look at the query plans, but don't be surprised if they're identical.

Answer (score 3):

They are parsed identically.

```
13:41:48 SYSTEM@oars_sandbox> create table t as select mod(rownum,5) val from dual connect by rownum <= 1e5;

Table created.                                                                                              

Elapsed: 00:00:00.21
```

Notice "column projection information". First case:

```
13:43:51 SYSTEM@oars_sandbox> ed                                                    
Wrote file S:\\tools\buffer.sql                                                     

  1  SELECT CASE val                                                                
  2           WHEN 1 THEN 'a'                                                       
  3           WHEN 2 THEN 'a'                                                       
  4           WHEN 3 THEN 'a'                                                       
  5           WHEN 5 THEN 'b'                                                       
  6         END AS case_column_str                                                  
  7    FROM t                                                                       
  8*  ORDER BY case_column_str                                                      
13:44:32 SYSTEM@oars_sandbox> @xplan                                                

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                   
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 961378228                                                          

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |   114K|  1450K|       |   591   (2)| 00:00:08 | 
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY     |      |   114K|  1450K|  2256K|   591   (2)| 00:00:08 | 
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |   114K|  1450K|       |    44   (3)| 00:00:01 | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):                       
-------------------------------------------------------------                       

   1 - SEL$1                                                                        
   2 - SEL$1 / T@SEL$1                                                              

Column Projection Information (identified by operation id):                         
-----------------------------------------------------------                         

   1 - (#keys=1) CASE "VAL" WHEN 1 THEN 'a' WHEN 2 THEN 'a' WHEN 3 THEN             
       'a' WHEN 5 THEN 'b' END [1]                                                  
   2 - "VAL"[NUMBER,22]                                                             

Note                                                                                
-----                                                                               
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)
```

Second case:

```
13:44:36 SYSTEM@oars_sandbox> ed                                                    
Wrote file S:\\tools\buffer.sql                                                     

  1  SELECT CASE WHEN val=1 OR val=2 OR val=3 THEN 'a'                              
  2           WHEN val=5 OR val=6 THEN 'b'                                          
  3    END AS case_column_str                                                       
  4    FROM t                                                              
  5*  ORDER BY case_column_str                                                      
13:45:53   6                                                                        
13:45:55 SYSTEM@oars_sandbox> @xplan                                                

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                   
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 961378228                                                          

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |   114K|  1450K|       |   591   (2)| 00:00:08 | 
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY     |      |   114K|  1450K|  2256K|   591   (2)| 00:00:08 | 
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |   114K|  1450K|       |    44   (3)| 00:00:01 | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):                       
-------------------------------------------------------------                       

   1 - SEL$1                                                                        
   2 - SEL$1 / T@SEL$1                                                              

Column Projection Information (identified by operation id):                         
-----------------------------------------------------------                         

   1 - (#keys=1) CASE "VAL" WHEN 1 THEN 'a' WHEN 2 THEN 'a' WHEN 3 THEN             
       'a' WHEN 5 THEN 'b' END [1]                                                  
   2 - "VAL"[NUMBER,22]                                                             

Note                                                                                
-----                                                                               
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)
```

Explain plan query:

```
  select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(null, null, 'all'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The two forms of CASE syntax allow us to use different conditions.

The first form is only relevant for filtering on a single column, but even then it is pretty rigid.  Given your example rule I would still opt to use the second variant, but with a less verbose formulation ...

```
CASE
    WHEN case_column in (1,2,3) THEN 'a'
    WHEN case_column in (5,6) THEN 'b'
    ELSE 'c'
END CASE
```

... or perhaps ...

```
CASE
    WHEN case_column <= 3 THEN 'a'
    WHEN case_column between 5 and 6 THEN 'b'
    ELSE 'c'
END CASE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have mentioned two kind of case statements.
1st example is of **normal case statement.**
2nd example is a **searched case statement.**

1st form is pretty much equivalent to **decode function of oracle**. So I don't see any particular use of this type of case.

Whereas 2nd form is like if else coding paradigm. Through this multiple conditions can be checked which otherwise cannot be checked in 1st form.

From performance perspective, there is no difference between two ways. When both queries are executed in SQL DEVELOPER, both queries are giving same cost value.

Hope this helps.!!

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT some_column,
CASE 
     WHEN case_column=1 or case_column=2 or case_column=3 THEN 'a'
     WHEN case_column=5 or case_column=6 THEN 'b'
     ...
END as case_column_str
FROM some_table order by case_column_str
```

This is far better as if any one of them is true in the case, we dont have to check the rest of the conditions

That is not the case with the first option, over there we would have to pass through each individual condition one by one.

Comment: Why do you believe short-circuit evaluation is impossible for the first option?

Comment: Doesnt the optimisation the first query take longer than the second. I know its not a considerable change but the question was which is better.

Comment: Not sure what you're driving at... the logic is pretty much the same, so the question is if short-circuit evaluation only occurs on one form vs. the other.

Comment: Certainly I can't see how you can justify "this is **far** better".

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/02_funds.htm#i37590 - Here it says "WHEN clauses, which are checked sequentially"

Comment: reading the very next sentence: "The value of the selector determines which clause is evaluated. The first WHEN clause that matches the value of the selector determines the result value, and subsequent WHEN clauses are not evaluated"